# Serialize from ul li with child using jqueryui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to know how to create a JSON or serialize (both is fine) from a ul including

```
<ul class="menu send ui-sortable">
<li id="pageid_1" class="ui-sortable-handle">Inscription
    <ul class="menu send ui-sortable">
         <li id="pageid_2" class="ui-sortable-handle">Joueurs en ligne
               <ul class="menu send ui-sortable"></ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I cannot find how to create something like this:

`pageid[]=1&pageid[1]=2` OR `[{"pageid":1,"children":[{"pageid":2}]}]`

Meaning, including parent ID in `[]`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your **exact** expected output - also, you'll be lucky if someone offers to write all the code for you

Comment: `pageid[]=1&pageid[1]=2` (pageid[parent pageid]=..)

Comment: so, from that input you've shown in the question, you expect that exact output ... that's not going to happen

Comment: How about manually create a JSON output? with .each() and looking for parents ID?

Comment: `manually create a JSON output` - how can you equate his expected output with JSON? it's not even CLOSE to JSON

Comment: Hey, think 2 sec. before being toxic.` [{"pageid":1,"children":[{"pageid":2}]}]` This could be possible too. I maybe need to change id style, and check parent ID.

Comment: Hey, think 1 sec before suggesting JSON is in the mix for the **expected output**, it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will produce the output required

```
var result = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu.send.ui-sortable li.ui-sortable-handle'), function(li) {
    var parent = '';
    if (li.parentNode && li.parentNode.parentNode && li.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI' && li.parentNode.parentNode.matches('li.ui-sortable-handle')) {
        parent = li.parentNode.parentNode.id.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    }
    return "pageid[" + parent + "]=" + li.id.replace(/\D+/g, '');
}).join('&');
console.log(result); // pageid[]=1&pageid[1]=2
```

I haven't thought about how to do the second format, because the first format is easier to produce

Comment: yeah, just because I argue with you about the use of the word JSON, doesn't mean I'm not doing something about it :p

Comment: Ahah, sorry about that. Thank you a lot